# How to receive push notification and update data using parse when app is in background

Tags: objective-c, background, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I need  start some process after receiving push notification using parse .If application is in foreground it is working fine,if app in background i am not receiving notification also & need to start some process.Here my code is :

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{ 
 if([[userInfo  objectForKey:@"operation"] isEqualToString:@"Start"])
    {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:userInfo   forKey:@"startNotification"];[start process];//this method i need to call after receive notification
    }else if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"operation"]isEqualToString:@"Update"])
    {
        NSLog(@"update notification called");
        [database updateDatabase:[userInfo objectForKey:@"Id"]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTableView" object:nil]; }}
```

My Environment :iOS8,Xcode 6.3,Mac10.10.
Thanks

Comment: have you found the solution? Mine is working only when the device is plugged in to USB charger.

Answer (score 0):

There are the steps which you need to do:-

1. First register your `appleId` to the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com) and then you need to register you Application id through this link:-

http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/register-app-id

2. Second you need to create the CertificateSigningRequest like that below:-
   Open `Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Request a Certificate From Certificate Authority` then it will prompt Certificate Assistant window inside that enter your registered email Address and Choose the radio button as Saved to Disk and click on continue.

Once it created, go to this https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action

Choose iOS Development and click on continue then you need to upload your CSR and then click on generate it will download one .CER file (with public key and private key) which you have to download and then double tap on that it will open in Keychain Access in which you have to right click on .CER file and export to .p12 file

3. Third, download the provisioning profile which should be associated to your APPlication ID from this link https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action
4. Fourth, you need to download the Push Profile Certificate for receiving the Push notification to your iOS App which should be associated to your Application ID . So click on this link:-https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action

Once downloaded the Push Profile Certificate double tap on .CER file and then export to .p12 file and then put the same file to the server for receiving Apple push notification.

*Note*:- your .cer file should have associated private key otherwise it will not work.

Hope this helps!